# How to get the T value from std::cmp::Reverse::<T>

Tags: rust, types, reverse, min-heap

I have a min-heap of `i32` in Rust, and I want to calculate the sum of its elements and store it in `i32`.

```
let mut total_sum = 0;
for current in min_heap {
    total_sum = current + total_sum;
}
```

I am getting the following error when compiling:

```
cannot add `{integer}` to `Reverse<i32>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call the `sum` method on your iterator after mapping  `Reverse<i32>`'s inside your heap to their inner values.

```rust
let total_sum: i32 = min_heap.into_iter()
                            .map(|i| i.0)
                            .sum();
```

Some advices:

1. Avoid mutations;
2. Don't use `x = x + y`, use `x += y` instead;
3. Don't use camelCase in function and variable names;
4. Don't use new-line braces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tuple accessor, `.0`, or use destructuring.

```
let mut total_sum = 0;
for current in min_heap {
    total_sum += current.0;
}
```

Or with destructuring:

```
let mut total_sum = 0;
for Reverse(current) in min_heap {
    total_sum += current;
}
```